# How to access handlebars varieables with post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

After taking input from /enter route then I redirect to /home route while storing username with req.session.message. In home.handlebars I can show username with curuser.username. Below is my app.js

```
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Handlebars = require('handlebars');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();
const { allowInsecurePrototypeAccess } = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access');
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const fs = require('fs');
const unirest = require('unirest');

// Connect to mongoose
mongoose.Promise=global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/codebie',{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology : true
})
.then(()=> console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

// Load Models
require('./models/User');
const User = mongoose.model('users');
require('./models/Problem');
const Problem = mongoose.model('problems');

// Body Parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// Express session
app.use(session({secret: 'mySecret', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false}));

// Handlebars Middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    defaultLayout:'main',
    handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars)
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// To use public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

// Middleware
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    next();
});

// Index route
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});


// Login/Signup Route
app.get('/enter',function(req,res){
    res.render('enter');
});

app.post('/enter',function(req,res){
    if(Object.keys(req.body).length==3){
        User.findOne({
            username : req.body.signinusername
        })
        .then(user =>{
            if(user){
                req.session.message = user;
                res.redirect('/home');
            } else {
                // else show error
            }
        });
    } else {
        const newUser = {
            username : req.body.signupusername,
            email : req.body.signupemail,
            password : req.body.signuppass,
        };
        new User(newUser)
        .save()
        .then(user => {
            res.redirect('/enter');
        }); 
        // else show error
    }
});

// Home Route
app.get('/home',function(req,res){
    var curuser = req.session.message;
    res.render('home', {curuser: curuser});
});

app.post('/home',function(req,res){
    Problem.find({tags:req.body.submit})
        .lean()
        .then(problems =>{
            req.session.message = problems;
            res.redirect('/problems');
        });
});

app.get('/problems',function(req,res){
    var curproblems = req.session.message;
    res.render('problems', {curproblems: curproblems});
});

app.post('/problems',function(req,res){
    console.log("Posted");
});


app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Then at home.handlebars, four buttons contain some strings as value.Below is example of one button

```
<form
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="java" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block btn-border mt-2" id="btn-solve">Practice</button>
</form>
```

When the button is clicked, I make a post request and get the value from req.body.submit. Then I redirect to problems route. However, there I cannot access curuser varieable in problems route. What changes should I make?

Comment: you cannot use re4direct and send your data to it

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: res.render('index', {data: "my_data"})

Comment: I know that but the problem is in app.post('/home',function(req,res){} I can not access curuser variable. I want this variable to pass to problems route also.

Comment: try to use authentication middleware for such use cases.